# when i am trying to deploy a stream in spring cloud dataflow server getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a sample code source,processor and sink applications as follows,which just take date and  process the date and will be given to the output, which i want to deploy and see the logs in the console but i am unable to do ..can anyone help me with this.

```
    Source:
     @EnableBinding(Source.class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SourceApplication {

        @Bean
        @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
        public MessageSource<Long> timeMessageSource() {

            return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Date().getTime()).build();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SourceApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

and processor:

```
    @EnableBinding(Processor.class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ProcessorApplication {

        @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
        public Object transform(Long date) {

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return dateFormat.format(date);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ProcessorApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

sink:

```
    @EnableBinding(Sink.class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SinkApplication {

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SinkApplication.class);

        @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
        public void loggerSink(String date) {

            logger.info("Received: " + date);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SinkApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

when i am trying to deploy getting the following error message

```
  com.example.source.SourceApp             : Starting SourceApp v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on HYD01-IkshwakLT with PID 13440 (C:\Users\ikshwak.vallala\.m2\repository\com\example\source\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\source-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by ikshwak.vallala in C:\Users\IKSHWA~1.VAL\AppData\Local\Temp\spring-cloud-deployer-8172224760963124756\data-1538225083194\data.source-app)
2018-09-29 18:14:52.553  INFO 13440 --- [           main] com.example.source.SourceApp             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-29 18:14:52.857  INFO 13440 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7cef4e59: startup date [Sat Sep 29 18:14:52 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-29 18:14:55.979  INFO 13440 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2018-09-29 18:14:57.797  INFO 13440 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2018-09-29 18:14:57.801  INFO 13440 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2018-09-29 18:14:58.196  INFO 13440 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1fc458ff] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-29 18:14:58.928  INFO 13440 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c44a5600] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-29 18:15:00.454  WARN 13440 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sourceApp': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
2018-09-29 18:15:00.487  INFO 13440 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-29 18:15:00.498 ERROR 13440 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sourceApp': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.source.SourceApp.main(SourceApp.java:24) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [source-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [source-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [source-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [source-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "true"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.configurePollingEndpoint(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:359) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(InboundChannelAdapterAnnotationPostProcessor.java:80) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.processAnnotationTypeOnMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I am running kafka server and spring cloud data flow server locally and trying to deploy the stream but it is getting failed with the above logs in the console.Can someone help me with this or can anyone provide me any reference ..

Comment: Hey, it seems as if you forgot to add the logs you're referring to... Could you attach them to your question?

Comment: can you check now

Comment: Take a look at the error message. Any idea where a `true` string may come from where a number is expected? Some context xml file maybe or an environment variable?